# Renaming one item of a level in pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with a structure similar to this:

```
Name    Location    Position   Data1    Data2
Foo     loc1        12345      present  absent
Foo2    loc2        67890      absent   present
```

where `Name`, `Location` and `Position` are the MultiIndex levels. However I need to rename one single level of the index: for this example I need to change `Foo2` to `Bar`.

I thought `DataFrame.rename()` would do the job, however if I specify

```
new_df = old_df.rename(index={"Foo2": "Bar"})
```

it doesn't really change the index, and worse, it flattens it.

Is what I'm looking to do possible? Or am I hitting a pandas bug?

Comment: Thanks, in the mean time I worked it around, I'll post my solution later outlining the open bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rename` function should convert the the dictionary to a mapper and apply it to each index. However, for the `MultiIndex` case, it only walk through each tuple but not each index.
I've fixed it and made a [pull request](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3175).

Comment: Thanks, I'll pull tomorrow morning and give it a go.